# Handling the current executing process in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to handle the current running process in JAVA, the processess that are running in WINDOWS. If we execute a file on our own (i.e the new process is created) should be displayed in program... The name of the process or the properties of process should be displayed.

Please Help me in getting to the answer..

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires access to the Windows API and is not possible in Java, except via the Java Native Interface or perhaps by running command line programs and processing their output. Theoretically, you could do that while still using a Java GUI, but it doesn't really make much sense.

It would be much easier to use .net for these requirements.

Comment: Please check my another question and answer if possible.
How to handle windows events in JAVA...